# How to show more items when click last item on a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I have to do a grid with some items, and it has to show exactly six items at a first moment, and when the user clicks at the last item, show the next items. I can do that using a RecyclerView and fixing the values? Here are how it should happens:

[image: First moment]

And after click:

[image: After click]